# Label1.text and Label1.backcolor don't change anything

Tags: vb.net

Uh, yeah. This one's pretty straight forward. I made a label in the form design section (Label1), and Label1.text isn't working.

```
Public Class Countdown

    Private WithEvents CountDwnTimer As New Timer() With {.Interval = 1000}
    Public CountdownValue = 6

    Private Sub Countdown_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

        AddHandler CountDwnTimer.Tick, AddressOf CountDwnTimer_Tick

        CountDwnTimer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CountDwnTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If CountdownValue > 0 Then
            CountdownValue -= 1
            Label1.Text = CountdownValue.ToString
        ElseIf CountdownValue = 0 Then
            CountDwnTimer.Stop()
            Me.BackColor = Color.White
            Me.Opacity = 100
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black
            Label1.BackColor = Color.White
            Label1.Text = "Capturing, don't move your mouse!"
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Error! Application flow interrupted.")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is my code. Note that the countdown works fine (this code changes the label to show a countdown), but when I try to do `Label1.Text = "Capturing, don't move your mouse!"` it doesn't work! Also, `Label1.BackColor = Color.White` does not work. It also seems to be just with the Label code, because the code after it works.

Am I just seeing right past an obvious issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, the changes you make to those properties can't actually show up until that method completes, but you immediately sleep the UI thread and then hide the form. You would need to call `Refresh` on the `Label` after setting its properties to force the changes to show up before executing the subsequent code.

Comment: Dare I utter "Application.DoEvents()"? (Best not ...)

Comment: @SteveCinq, that would presumably work, but I'd tend to be more explicit and refresh the `Label` specifically. That said, I probably wouldn't need to because, rather than sleeping the UI thread for 2 seconds, I'd probably use a `Timer` to delay those two seconds before acting, in which case the UI thread is available to refresh the `Label` naturally.

Comment: I was alluding to the fact that `DoEvents()` has a bad rep and often gets labelled as a code smell. I avoid it as much as possible, but, well, er, um ... (BTW, I couldn't tag you in this comment, possibly because you're also the author of the answer. Dunno.)